# How to add more information to first html page sent by meteor server

Tags: meteor

Is there anyway we can add data like in php `echo "something"` in the first html page. I want to know the server's timestamp to format a document created time like *2 hours ago*, the document already has a property `createdTime`. When I use `Meteor.Collection.find`, I cannot add the server time by using `transform`.

I can use `Meteor.method` but I may have to format time before the result arrives.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after digging around the code, here is the answer.
You can use the global variable `__meteor_runtime_config__` to add more information to the first downloaded html file. In my case, in a server side javascript file, I add `__meteor_runtime_config__.now = new Date().getTime()` and this value will be available on the client side

Answer (score 0):

the `__meteor_runtime_config__` approach is run-once; that is, only changes made at package load time (not `Meteor.startup()`) are taken into account, and then the `__meteor_runtime_config__` snippet is [frozen](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/1bdaa048139c3b38c1127a6cdf6e8f811495a2f5/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js#L159).

To pass run-time (per-page) metadata to the page, it looks like the [only option](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/1bdaa048139c3b38c1127a6cdf6e8f811495a2f5/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js#L248) is to set a custom tag on the `<html>` element using the (public, but undocumented) [`WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/1bdaa048139c3b38c1127a6cdf6e8f811495a2f5/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js#L132) API.